# Union of disjoint sets

Tags: merge, hashtable, union-find

I am looking at disjoint sets that support the function of the Union.

The technique of  height reduction of a tree:

We always merge the smaller tree to the greater one, i.e. we make the root of the smaller tree to point to the root of the greater tree.

A tree is greater than an other if it has more nodes.

Each node is a struct with fields: some information for the element, the pointer "parent" to the parent node, and a counter "count", that is used only if the node is the root and contains the number of the nodes at the up-tree.

The following algorithm merges two up trees:

```
pointer UpTreeUnion(pointer S,T) {
   if (S == NULL OR P == NULL) return;
   if (S->count >= T->count) {
       S->count = S->count + T->count;
       T->parent = S;
       return S;
   }
   else {
       T->count = T->count + S->count;
       S->parent = T;
       return T;
   }
}
```

Consider an implementation of disjoint sets with union, where there can be at most k disjoint sets. 
The implementation uses a hash table A[0.. max-1] at which there are stored keys based on the method ordered double hashing.
Let h1 and h2 be the primary and the secondary hash function, respectively. A contains the keys of the nodes of all of the above trees and also a pointer to the corresponding node  for each of them.
I want to write an algorithm that takes as parameters the keys of two nodes and merges the up-trees to which the nodes belong (the nodes can belong to any up-trees, even at the same in which case it appears an appropriate message). At merging, we should apply techniques of path compression and height reduction.

Could you give me a hint how we could do this?

Suppose that we have this array:

[image]

At the beginning the nodes will be like that:

[image]

Then if k1=100, k2=5, after applying the algorithm, will we get this?

[image]

Then if we have k1=59, k2=5, we will get the following:

[image]

Right? Then applying the path compression we start doing this:

```
tmp=B
while (B->parent!=B)
      parent=B->parent;
      tmp->parent=B;
      tmp=parent;
}
```

So we will have parent=F, tmp->parent=B, tmp=F.

How do we continue?

Having then k1=14, k2=59 we get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you get keys, you need to find them in the hash table.
Hash table contains entries: `(key, pointer-to-node)`.
Let's say you want to find key `k`. You check:
`A[h1(k) + 0*h2(k) mod size(A)]` - if it contains key `k`, you read corresponding pointer-to-node.
If there is something other than `k`, you check:
`A[h1(k) + 1*h2(k) mod size(A)]`,
`A[h1(k) + 2*h2(k) mod size(A)]`,
`A[h1(k) + i*h2(k) mod size(A)]`... until you find key `k`.

Now that you have pointers to 2 nodes, you need to find roots of the trees those nodes belong to. To find the root, you go up the tree until you reach root node. You use `parent` pointer of each node for it and you can assume that root's `parent` pointer points to itself for example.

Now that you have 2 roots, you can merge them using `upTreeUnion`.

Path compression works like this:

[image]

After you have found root of a tree for node `s`, you follow the path from `s` to root one more time and set `parent` pointer of every node on the path to the root.

**Update:**

```
Algorithm(k1,k2){
   int i=0,j=0;
   int i1,i2;
   while (i<max and A[i1 = h1(k1)+i*h2(k1) mod size(A)]->key!=k1){
          i++;
   }
   while (j<max and A[i2 = h1(k2)+j*h2(k2) mod size(A)]->key!=k2){
          j++;
   }
   if (A[i1]->key!=k1) return;
   if (A[i2]->key!=k2) return;

   pointer node1,node2,root1,root2;
   node1=A[i1]->node;
   node2=A[i2]->node;
   root1=UpTreeFind(node1);
   root2=UpTreeFind(node2);
   if (root1==root2){
      printf("The nodes belong to the same up tree");
      return;
   }

   // path compression
   pointer tmp,tmpParent;

   tmp = node1;
   while (tmp->parent!=root1) {
       tmpParent=tmp->parent;
       tmp->parent=root1;
       tmp=tmpParent;
   }

   tmp = node2;
   while (tmp->parent!=root2) {
       tmpParent=tmp->parent;
       tmp->parent=root2;
       tmp=tmpParent;
   }

   UpTreeUnion(root1,root2);
}
```

Comment: MD-11 Could you explain me further how path compression works?

So, should the algorithm look like that: http://pastebin.com/HsT8fN7s ?

Comment: Yes, it generally looks OK for me (you have some errors/typos in indexes). I updated my answer with your modified code - I changed those indexes and added path compression.

Comment: Nice, thank you!!! Do we have to declare the fields of A, i.e. that it has the field key and the field node?

Also, could you explain me what the function of path compression is?

Comment: Well, it's pseudocode anyway, so we don't have to declare those fields. If it's a course assignment just write it in natural language as an assumption. As to the function of path compression - UpTreeFind function has to go from given node to the root. The path from this node to the root may be long. If you compress this path, next time UpTreeFind is called, the path will be a lot shorter, because compression attaches nodes on the path straight to the root. You can see it in my picture.

Comment: And shorter path means that UpTreeFind will work faster.
Example - look at the left tree on my picture. If you call UpTreeFind(D), it has to follow this path: D->B->A->E before it finds root (3 edges). Now look on the tree on the right (with compressed path from D to E): if you call UpTreeFind(D) on this tree, it just needs to follow one edge: D->E and it finds the root. So, path compression improves performance.

Comment: I will take a look at it tomorrow and I will tell you if I have understood it... :)

Comment: MD-11 At the beginning, do we assume that there are k sets and we look at all of them seperately and then we merge them?

Comment: Define beggining and k, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I want to apply the algorithm at an example to check if I have uderstood it..  At the beginning are there k up-trees, and each of them contain only one node?

Comment: Yes, that's the most common use-case.

Comment: MD-11 I am trying to apply the algorithm at an exmaple and edited my post.. Could you take a look at it and tell me if it is right?

Comment: Nice :) Now I did an other up-tree union and edited my post.. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: Oops, there was a mistake in my code - you compress the path before upTreeUnion, not after. Excuse me for confusing you, I've updated my code. So, for B, path compression will do nothing, because before union, B is root of a single node tree. For D, it will re-attach it to F, so it also won't do anything in the end. I also updated condition in while loop, so that it doesn't reattach root's children. To see how path compression works you need higher trees - after more unions.

Comment: Now I made an other union and edited my post.. Which nodes could I take so that I see how path compression works?

Comment: As I wrote, you need **higher** trees, not wider (as in the picture in my answer). You can evaluate the following merge sequence (notation: A(1,2) = Algorithm(k1=1,k2=2)): A(100,5), A(13,19), A(100,13), A(44,19), starting with all trees containing only one node.

Comment: When we call the function A(44,19) we will find root1=F, root2=E but in order to find root2 we follow the path A->E->F. Is this the shortest possible path?

Comment: How did you get root1=F? `44` is the key of `G` node, so root1=G and to find root2 we indeed follow A->E->F, which gives us root2=F, not E.

Comment: Oh, yes sorry.. I found the same results, I was looking somewhere else.. Could you explain me why it is more efficient, applying path compression?

Comment: Well, I explained it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710752/union-of-disjoint-sets/27714250?noredirect=1#comment43884810_27714250) (4th and 5th comment). Is there something unclear for you?

Comment: I see.. but in the example that we did we haven't seen such a case where the UpTreeFind follows a shorter path to find the root, have we?

Comment: No, we haven't, but now, if you called A(59,19) it would find root of 19's tree in one step (A -> F). If we hadn't compressed the path, it would have needed to follow (A -> E -> F) again (2 steps instead of 1). Of course it doesn't make a difference if we need 1 step or 2, but as the trees grow, the difference becomes more significant.

Comment: I have also an other question.. At these two commands:


 tmp->parent=root1; and tmp=parent;


is parent at the one command a field and at the other one a variable? Or are we talking about the same variable?

Comment: The first option - they are different (a field and a variable).

Comment: A ok.. So would it be better to define the variable otherwise?

Comment: I don't find it confusing, but maybe you are right, I could have named it `tmpParent` for example. I'm sorry if it made it difficult to understand for you.